# Heroku Push Rejected - Cannot find gem multipart-post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I finished setting up OAuth in my app, but I can't seem to push to Heroku. There is a gem dependency that was installed (and everything works locally), but Heroku rejects the push.

I have tried deleted my .lock file, .bundle, and have tried bundle update as well. Heroku will not accept the push

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Could not find multipart-post-2.0.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Could not find multipart-post-2.0.0 in any of the sources
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

The gem is supposed to be `multipart-post` (version 2.0.0), but for some reason it is including the version as part of the gem file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/multipart-post/versions/2.0.0) site & use proper version format such as

```
gem 'multipart-post', '~> 2.0'
```

and again commit lifecycle & see what happens